# ¿Es correcto decir "tiene muchos vericuetos" cuando alguna tarea/actividad es dificil de concretar?

Tags: uso-de-palabras

Según WordReference:

> [vericueto](http://www.wordreference.com/definicion/vericueto) m. Sitio alto y accidentado por el que es difícil andar: hay que andar por muchos vericuetos para llegar a la cima del monte.
>
> pl. Partes o aspectos más difíciles o escondidos de algo: los vericuetos de la ley.

Pero no me consta que estos sean todos sus significados.

Por ejemplo, ¿se podría usar la frase "tiene muchos vericuetos" para hablar de la dificultad que tiene un procedimiento o un protocolo para ejecutarse, que necesita de muchas vueltas para utilizarse? (Por ejemplo, una operación matemática, un algoritmo, etc)

El primer significado citado por WordReference se le parece pero está claro que no tiene nada que ver con un sitio alto, aunque si son "lugares" difíciles de andar (entendiéndose por andar ir recorriendo y ejecutando los pasos de un procedimiento). ¿Puede utilizarse de esta manera o tiene la palabra "vericuetos" más significados que se puedan ajustar a esta idea?

Comment: Sí. Pero esa tarea difícil de concretar debe tener muchas ramificaciones o posibilidades.

Comment: Yo la usaría pero no hablando de la dificultad de la tarea en términos de esfuerzo sino de que hay muchas posibilidades de tomar el camino equivocado. Haciendo analogía con un camino no seria el camino más empinado (esfuerzo) sino el camino con mas ramificaciones y posibilidades de perderse antes de llegar al objetivo.

Answer (score 1):

Sí es correcto el uso de "Tiene muchos vericuetos." en el caso de querer indicar que tiene muchas *complicaciones*.
De todas maneras, el uso de "vericuetos" no sería correcto como necesariamente *dificultad*. Por ejemplo, la tarea de levantar algo pesado puede ser difícil, pero no tiene vericuetos, porque no tiene mucha complejidad. 
La frase se puede usar, además de relacionada con tareas, para referirse a cualquier *cosa* con complejidad de alguna índole. Por ejemplo, una novela puede tener muchos vericuetos en su trama, si es un policial, o también en su redacción, si es un estilo muy cargado. Sin embargo, el último uso de "vericuetos" ya es medio forzado.
Espero que te sirva.